# Concatenating the columns in each row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a selected range of cells. Need to concatenate all the columns in it and record the result in the first cell of the row (A first column in the selection). I'm trying to write following code

```
Dim row As Object
Dim col As Object
Dim cell_concat As String

For Each row In Selection
    cell_concat = ""
    For Each col In row
        cell_concat = cell_concat & col.Value
    Next col
    `How to record in first cell?
Next row
```

But this method unfortunately does not work and I can't figure out how to record `cell_concat` in the first cell of the row. What am I doing wrong and what to fix in the code?

Comment: first in that row like column A or first column in the selection?

Comment: A first column in the selection

Answer (score 1):

This will concatenate the values into the first cell in each row chosen:

```
Dim rw As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim cell_concat As String

For Each rw In Selection.Rows
    cell_concat = ""
    For Each col In rw.Cells
        cell_concat = cell_concat & col.Value
    Next col
    rw.Cells(1, 1).Value = cell_concat
Next row
```

Comment: What if the entire row isn't selected?  Would you need Selection.Columns(1).Column to get the number of the first selected column? And rw.Row for the row number?

Comment: No rw will be a range including each row of the selected range as it iterated.  So if you choose A1:H9  rw will first be A1:H9 then A2:H9 then ...  Then the col will iterate through each cell in those ranges individually concatenating the values.  Then rw.Cells(1:1) will always refer to the cell in the first column.  Even if the selection is one cell it will work.  It would not appear to do anything as it will just put the value that was there back in.  It can be just one row or one column and it will work just fine.

Comment: Cells is relative to the parent.  When using the `worksheet.Cells(1,1)` it will refer to `A1`, but if `rw` where a range `B1:D1` then `rw.Cells(1,1)` will refer to `B1`. @mooseman

Comment: Wow.  thanks Scott.  I did not know that Cells were relative